# Duplicated Windows firewall rules (Netsh AdvFirewall firewall)

Tags: windows, firewall, rules, netsh, idempotent

I've noticed that when we create a firewall rule through `netsh advfirewall firewall`, it can be run multiple times, creating multiple identical firewall rules.

Is there any way of checking if the firewall rule exists before attempting to create a new one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to get this going through PowerShell's Network Security Cmdlets, the following code will check for a named firewall rule along with a specified local port, if it finds an entry, it does not create the rule. If it does not find an entry, it will create the rule

```
$firewallPort = ""
$firewallRuleName = ""

write-host "Checking for '$firewallRuleName' firewall rule on port '$firewallPort' now...."
if ($(Get-NetFirewallRule –DisplayName $firewallRuleName | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where { $_.LocalPort -eq $firewallPort }))
{
    write-host "Firewall rule for '$firewallRuleName' on port '$firewallPort' already exists, not creating new rule"
}
else
{
    write-host "Firewall rule for '$firewallRuleName' on port '$firewallPort' does not already exist, creating new rule now..."
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $firewallRuleName -Direction Inbound -Profile Domain,Private,Public -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort $firewallPort -RemoteAddress Any
    write-host "Firewall rule for '$firewallRuleName' on port '$firewallPort' created successfully"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Check if rule "myrule" not exists

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="myrule" | findstr "no rules"
```

Comment: It is not safe to parse the result text for english words, because the user might have a different OS langauge - or the wording might eventually change.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Oleg's answer, here is what I use. Replace the ... according to the criteria for your rule.

```
set name="my rule"
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=!name! >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Adding firewall rule !name!
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=!name! ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

why nobody mentioned the || operator for failures in batch?
the opposite of the && success operator

```
:: (if command errors) || (exec this command)
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="myrule" >nul || netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="myrule" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Command -Module NetSecurity
get-help Get-NetFirewallRule -full
```

Comment: [answer], [tour]

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.